# Express Send data via request body but request methode is GET?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hey there It's my first post so sorry if I am doing something wrong here but be patient with me ;)

I am trying to send some data in JSON format to my MySQL DB using Express but whenever I use something else besides app.get() it fails. I guess it is because the request methode shown in the browser is always GET but I dont know why. 
What am I doing wrong? How can the request method be GET when I am using app.post()?

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'masterkey',
    database: 'articelStorage'
});

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

//connect to db
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Myql connected...');
});

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server started and running on port 3000...');
});

app.get('/getOne/:code', (req, res) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM articels WHERE acode ='" +req.params.code+"'";
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
            res.send(result);
    });
});

app.delete('/deleteOne/:code', (req, res) => {
    let sql = "DELETE FROM articels WHERE acode ='" +req.params.code+ "'";
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
            res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Here is the result I get:

```
Cannot GET /deleteOne/DE12345678
```

And the Headers:

General:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/deleteOne/DE12345678
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 159
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 13:12:36 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;
        q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you use (the front-end part) to call your api? Are you trying to call your endpoint directly from the browser? If so, the method will always be GET. You can test your API using tools like Postman : https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misconception here.

When you are declaring `app.get('/getOne/:code', (req, res)=>{..})` it means the route is accessible by **`HTTP GET`**. Similarly for `app.delete` the route is accessible by request method **`HTTP DELETE`**.

Now, when you open a url in browser it is ALWAYS a `HTTP GET` request. That's why the `/getOne` will work, but not the `delete` one.

You need to use Postman(or curl) like application to test your REST api.

If you are accessing an endpoint from Client, use [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) or `xmlhttprequest` and set the request method what you want it to be.

For example,

```
axios({url:url, method:'delete', { data: { foo: "bar" } });// or axios.delete(..)
```